# How can I upload a file from my web UI to directly Amazon S3?

Tags: php, html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I have a PHP code to upload file from my local system to Amazon S3. Also I have PHP webpage which make user to upload a file and submit. ow my requirement is I need to upload user uploaded file directly to Amazon S3. Is there a way to upload file directly from UI to Amazon S3 without keeping it in system.? if there is a way how can I do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can very much do that without keeping any system in between using [sdk-for-javascript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html)

You can refer to the [sample web page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html) that does exactly that.

Following is the code snippet from that page

```
function addPhoto(albumName) {
  var files = document.getElementById('photoupload').files;
  if (!files.length) {
    return alert('Please choose a file to upload first.');
  }
  var file = files[0];
  var fileName = file.name;
  var albumPhotosKey = encodeURIComponent(albumName) + '//';

  var photoKey = albumPhotosKey + fileName;
  s3.upload({
    Key: photoKey,
    Body: file,
    ACL: 'public-read'
  }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return alert('There was an error uploading your photo: ', err.message);
    }
    alert('Successfully uploaded photo.');
    viewAlbum(albumName);
  });
}
```

For setting your credentials to the SDK from browser scripts following are the ways in order of recommendation:

1. Using Amazon Cognito Identity to authenticate users and supply credentials
2. Using web federated identity
3. Hard coded in the script

More details about setting the credentials can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-browser.html)

Comment: And what about authorization? Just for note, you can use pre-signed urls to upload on behalve of your account

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try this and get back later.